# Turning text-strings into (Cartesian) graphs

Tags: coordinate-systems

A friend told me of a neat site that could turn a text string into an equation for plotting that string, but he forgot to bookmark it.

Various web searches haven't helped (the more obvious terms like graph, string, equation are too noisy).

Could anyone offer any pointers?

Comment: What you’re looking for seems to be closely related to [Tupper’s self-referential formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupper%27s_self-referential_formula), discussed in a little more detail [here](http://avitzur.hax.com/2007/01/the_library_of_babel_function.html).

Comment: Brian - this is fascinating stuff, but not what I was looking for: I believe that the graphs I'm referring to were drawn with straight lines. Presumably this means that equations in question are all inequalities in two variables...

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've now found it:
http://www.xamuel.com/inverse-graphing-calculator.php?phrase=Tony

Hope you think it's as cool as I do!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out in google: cos(x)^2 (if I understood what you are looking for correctly).

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm looking for is something that, given (say) the text string "Tony" will produce an equation which (when plotted in the Cartesian plane), looks like the word "Tony".